# How to create a custom debian liveCD (customize which packages are preinstalled)?

Tags: debian, livecd

How would I do this? I have tried simple-cdd, but it did not work:

```
$ build-simple-cdd 
FINISHED --2013-08-28 17:57:11--
Total wall clock time: 51s
Downloaded: 54 files, 5.5M in 9.9s (568 KB/s)
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default-base' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default-udebs' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default-security' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
aptmethod error receiving 'http://security.debian.org/dists/precise/updates/Release':
'404  Not Found [IP: 195.20.242.89 80]'
aptmethod error receiving 'ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/precise/Release':
'Unable to fetch file, server said â€˜Failed to open file.  â€™ [IP: 64.50.236.52 21]'
aptmethod error receiving 'ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/precise/Release':
'Unable to fetch file, server said â€˜Failed to open file.  â€™ [IP: 64.50.236.52 21]'
aptmethod error receiving 'ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/precise/Release':
'Unable to fetch file, server said â€˜Failed to open file.  â€™ [IP: 64.50.236.52 21]'
There have been errors!
gzip: /home/samuel/Documents/custom-debian/tmp//mirror/lists/precise_default_deb_main_amd64.gz: No such file or directory
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `/home/samuel/Documents/custom-debian/tmp//mirror/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages' for reading (No such file or directory)
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default-base' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default-udebs' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Warning: No VerifyRelease line in 'default-security' or any rule it includes via 'From:'.
Release.gpg cannot be checked unless you tell which key to check with.
(To avoid this warning and not check signatures add 'VerifyRelease: blindtrust').
Error opening '/home/samuel/Documents/custom-debian/tmp//mirror/lists/default-security_precise%2Fupdates_Release': No such file or directory
There have been errors!
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `/home/samuel/Documents/custom-debian/tmp//mirror/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages' for reading (No such file or directory)
cat: /home/samuel/Documents/custom-debian/tmp//mirror/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages: No such file or directory
Merging...                                                          0      Fatal error: exception Failure("Warning: package ignored because it has no name")
```

Comment: How did you try it? Any messages? Have you read the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD)?

Comment: @terdon wait, I'll post a paste.

Comment: You might also benefit from the low-level [Debian Live Manual](http://live.debian.net/manual/3.x/html/live-manual.en.html)

Comment: @terdon http://paste.ubuntu.com/6037308/plain/

Comment: @JosephR. Thanks, that looks like what I need.

Comment: It hardly seems like light reading, though. I never used it, I only know it's out there in case I need it...

Comment: In the future, please don't paste to sites that require a log in, it makes it a pain to read. Try something like pastebin.com instead. Oh, and please also include the command you ran not just its output.

Comment: @terdon sorry, I didn't know that required logon. The command was build-simple-cdd

Comment: @handuel take a look on debian blends: Debian Pure Blends

Terminology
Debian Pure Blend
    a subset of Debian that is configured to support a particular target group out-of-the-box. 
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianPureBlends

Answer (score 0):

I have used remastersys and it worked very well for the supported debian systems as shown in their homepage.

http://www.remastersys.com/